# Are disposable fields of disposable classes disposed of automatically

Tags: c#

My question is fairly straightforward: If a class that implements `IDisposable` has fields which are also disposable, will disposing of the instance also dispose of the field values?

**Example:**

Say I have a class, `OuterDisposable`, which has a field `innerDisposable`, who's type is another disposable class:

```
public class OuterDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private InnerDisposable innerDisposable;
}
```

I intend to wrap all instances of `OuterDisposable` in a `using` statement so that they are disposed of automatically and safely:

```
using (var outerDisposable = new OuterDisposable())
{
    // Stuff
}
```

However, I'm not sure what will happen to `innerDisposable` once the end of the `using` is reached. It is very important that it is disposed of correctly, so I need to be sure what the behavior will be.

I presume explicitly disposing of `innerDisposable` will achieve my desired result:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.innerDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

But is this necessary? If the outer `using` statement takes care of disposing `innerDisposable` as well as `outerDisposable`, then it is redundant.

So, how are such disposable fields handled?

Comment: No, `OuterDisposable.Dispose` method must take care of it, `using` just ensures that `Dispose` is called.

Comment: the `using` that wrapps the `IDisposable` class only calls the `Dispose` function of the `IDisposable`, it does not check the properties of the object for IDisposable properties so your assumption is correct

Comment: You can easily check the behaviour for yourself by just putting some kind of debug statement in the dispose method of inner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IDisposable` is an interface and a pattern. It's not really part of the C# language, outside of explicit support in `using` and `foreach`. Nothing happens "automatically".

Consider, contrariwise, if this disposal did happen automatically. And consider further that it's perfectly valid for a class to hold a reference to a *shared* resource of some kind that may be disposable. You would have to invent new syntax to then be able to "opt out" of this automatic disposal that you were looking for.

C# is a simpler language by not having such a feature. It's always your responsibility to clean up `IDisposable` objects at a time when you, the programmer, know that they're no longer being used. Often, for a class such as the one here, that will be when your own `Dispose` method is being called.